# Multiple Navigation Controller Back Button

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an application that looks like this;

Navigation Controller->Table View Controller->Navigation Controller2->Table View Controller2

The problem that I'm facing is that I want to have a "Back" button on Table View Controller2 that will take me back to the very first Navigation Controller. I can't figure out how to do this for the life of me, except by placing a button in the Table View Controller2's Navigation bar and creating a modal seque back to the first navigation controller. I don't think Apple will like that though. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NavigationController *nav = [[NavigationController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nav animated:YES];                
[nav release];
```

Comment: Could you share a Swift3 version of this? Where does the code need to go?